# Next.js call fetch in page.tsx with app router to django rest API - Best Practices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js

ok guys - ive been messing with next.js for about 5 months now - with the app router and server components/route handlers, etc.  I am INSANELY confused as to what the proper way to go about simply creating a page in the app router, which can OR can not be a server component - the page.tsx component im referring to.  It's better to keep the page.tsx a server component i THINK - for metadata and for speed of fetching data on the server.

My issues im so confused:

1. When fetching data in a Page component, is it best to make the Page async and call a route handler? or call a normal fetch to the API?

**Folder Structure:**

```
project
-app
--api
---posts
  |-route.ts
--blog
  |-page.tsx
```

route.ts

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server"

export async function GET(req:NextRequest) {
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST}/api/posts`, {
      next: { revalidate: 60 }, // Revalidate every 60 seconds
    })

    const { results } = await res.json()
    
    return NextResponse.json(results)
  }
```

then in the Page Component:

blog/Page.tsx

```
export default async function Page({ params }: { params: { postSlug: string } }) {


// get data via route handler
  const res = await fetch(`/api/posts`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  });

  const post = await res.json();

  return (
      <>
         {posts.map(p => ( <Link> <Image /> </Link> )}
       </>
)
}
```

Or get the data via regular fetch in the Page?

```
export default async function Page({ params }: { params: { postSlug: string } }) {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST}/api/posts/`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  });

  const post = await res.json();

 return (
      <>
         {posts.map(p => ( <Link> <Image /> </Link> )}
       </>
)
}
```

OR get data in page componenet via regular fetch:

So 1. Which is the best way to accomplish this?  i just need to fetch json from an api and then render html from it.

2. Additionally if we add the Link or Image componenets, that seems to be an issue as well? how do we handle these client component issues and also fetch data?!
   if I have a Page component that i want to keep a server component in order to fetch data with - either via fetch  in the Pag component OR via route handlers( which i think is the best way)

Can anyone show some quick examples of how to fetch data in the app router, and then use that data to build html components with Image, Link or 3rd party components that rely on the client?!

I'd really appreciate it.  Also, can anyone quickly explain the USE of route handlers and if im doing it right in my example? all the tutorials if ever seen all show how to WRITE THEM, but none ever show how or where the route handlers GET CALLED AND USED, maybe im misunderstanding this whle thing hopefully yall can help me clear stuff up. thanks!!

------------------- **UPDATE** --------------------------

Ok - hopefully this will help someone as well as myself.  After researching and finally finding what i needed in the docs( i am not marking this as an answer yet as i have not gotten the answer, a clear answer, as to the usage of client components inside server components, i thought that was an anti pattern, it says in the docs not to do that but then its in examples everywhere - im lost on that still but will update that part when i figure it out or when one of you explains how to , in a server component when fetched data - how to then render that data inside a client components - like next-ui components library or something

1. Data fetching:  Route handlers ARE ONLY TO BE USED IN CLIENT COMPONENTS!  THEY ARE MEANT TO RENDER FETCH CALLS ON THE SERVER FOR CLIENT COMPONENTS!  That's why when i was calling route handlers from a server component, it errored out.
2. In a server component, there's no need to use route handlers, since route handlers are intended to make server side fetch calls, and we're already on the damn server - that's not going to work.  You can just use normal fetch calls when in a server componenet - make it an async function and just make ur fetch call w await/async.

**3.  As far as the rendering the html components on the server componenet - im working on that one still - will post here soon**